# Set value to a UILabel in another UIView Controller in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my app i have implemented a Facebook user login and Email user login.

[image]

And also in my app there is Slide out sidebar.

[image]

So my email user login is working properly without any error. Now **i want to set the Menu's User name with the name i've got from logged in user**. In facebook user login i've done that easily using Facebook SDK.

so how i set value to a UILable which is in another UIView Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a notification once you have your user name:

```
let userInfo: [String:AnyObject] = [ "userName": "John"]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("logged", object: userInfo)
```

And add an observer to the view controller that you want to load the loggedUserName:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "setName:", name: "logged", object: nil)
}

func setName(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.object as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let loggedUserName = userInfo["userName"] as? String {
            println(loggedUserName)
            yourLabel.text = loggedUserName
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: wow thanx that was quick. I've did it earlier for Facebook login thing. Now only i figured it out. Thnax for the quick reply! Appreciate it!